# HasCode Implementation for search String in Amazon Like Application

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hash

I wanted to design amazon like application, where I wanted to store all the product details in a particular data structure.

I thought of using hashing like data structure (similar to concurrent hash map which will be having a hashmaps in hashmap) as the time Complexity would be O(1)

for example: My main keys would be like **Mens's Section**, **Women's Section**, **Children's Section** and so on.

Inside **Men's section** action again using one more map I will having different keys like **causal wear**, **formal wear** and so on...

I wanted to write the effective hashing algorithm, for the effective search mechanism.

Can someone please guide how can i derive the hashing algorithm for this particular operation.

Comment: Are you looking to build this in Java?  The `HashMap` implementation with `String` already is pretty good.

Comment: A `Map<R, Map<C, V>>` is sometimes referred to as a `Table<R, C, V>`.  You should look into Guava's implementation.

Comment: [Bigtable: A Distributed Storage System for Structured Data](https://ai.google/research/pubs/pub27898)

Comment: I understand the outer hashmap, so you can look up a product by its key. But why the inner hashmap?